# Debugging jQuery load() for links in content replaced by load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-load

In my main.js I have two link related rules.  One should handle all links that do not start with http://, mailto:, or #.  It uses load() to replace content in $('#contentMain').  The other handles links that do start with http:// and opens them in a new tab.

```
$("a:not([href^='http://'],[href^='#'],[href^='mailto:'])").click( function(e) { 
    console.log('Caught click, loading via AJAX');
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var title = ($(this).attr("title")) ? ': ' + $(this).attr("title") : '';
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(url!=window.location){
       window.history.pushState({path:url},title,url);
       $('#contentMain').load(url);
        document.title = "It's New Orleans" + title;   
    }
});

$("a[href^='http://']").attr("target","_blank");
```

The problem seems to be that links like /contact do not trigger the first rule **IF** they are inside $('#contentMain') after load() has replaced content **on the first time they are clicked**.  If you click /contact inside #contentMain while /content is loaded then the rule is obeyed, you see the console.log() etc.

**So why would content replaced by load() not obey rules in main.js?**  Those rules are currently inside of a `$(document).ready(function(){` but I also tried removing it to see if it helped.

Comment: Don't think of them as rules, think of them as properties. You gave properties to the original ones, however the new ones don't have those properties. you'll either have to use event delegation, or re-bind those events when new elements are added.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB! Googled it and found http://jqueryfordesigners.com/simple-use-of-event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler, like this:

```
$("body" ).on( "click", "a:not([href^='http://'],[href^='#'],[href^='mailto:'])",function(e) { 
console.log('Caught click, loading via AJAX');
var url = $(this).attr("href");
var title = ($(this).attr("title")) ? ': ' + $(this).attr("title") : '';
e.preventDefault(); 
if(url!=window.location){
   window.history.pushState({path:url},title,url);
   $('#contentMain').load(url);
    document.title = "It's New Orleans" + title;   
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Per @KevinB's comment the answer is replacing with

```
$("body").delegate("a:not([href^='http://'],[href^='#'],[href^='mailto:'])", "click", function(e) { 
    console.log('Caught click, loading via AJAX');
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var title = ($(this).attr("title")) ? ': ' + $(this).attr("title") : '';
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(url!=window.location){
       window.history.pushState({path:url},title,url);
       $('#contentMain').load(url);
        document.title = "It's New Orleans" + title;   
    }
});
```

Comment: .delegate() has been superseded by .on(), you should use that instead since jQuery 1.7.